# Finalization in Pipes-2.1.0 package

Tags: haskell, monads, categories, monad-transformers, loops

I am using the Pipes-2.1.0 package and the zeromq3-haskell package to construct a little message pipeline. Everything seems to be going well except that I am having trouble understanding finalization of Frames.

In the following Frame I acquire two resources; a zeromq context, and a zeromq socket. Then I continuously wait for messages (in the form of `ByteStrings`) to publish on the zeromq socket.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module PipesZeroMQ where

import           Control.Frame
import           Control.IMonad.Do
import           Control.IMonad.Trans
import qualified Control.Monad          as M
import           Data.ByteString        (ByteString)
import           Data.String
import           Prelude                hiding (Monad(..))
import qualified System.ZMQ3            as ZMQ

type Address = String

fromList :: (M.Monad m) => [b] -> Frame b m (M a) (M a) ()
fromList xs = mapMR_ yield xs

publisher :: Address -> Frame Void IO (M ByteString) C ()
publisher addr = do
  c  <- liftU $ ZMQ.init 1
  s  <-liftU $ ZMQ.socket c ZMQ.Pub
  liftU $ ZMQ.bind s addr   
  liftU $ print "Socket open for business!!!"

  foreverR $ do
    bs <- await
    finallyF (ZMQ.close s M.>> ZMQ.term c M.>> print "ZMQ socket closed") $ do
         (liftU $ ZMQ.send s [] bs)
         (liftU (print "Sending message"))
```

Now if I try this:

```
λ> runFrame $ (publisher localAddress) <-< (fromList ["This", "that", "that"] >> close)
```

I get this:

```
"Socket open for business"
"Sending message"
"ZMQ socket closed"
*** Exception: ZMQError { errno = 88, source = "send", message = "Socket operation on non-socket" }
```

`publisher` finalizes after receiving but one `BytesString`.

Why is this happening?

What am I misunderstanding about finalization using Frames in Pipes-2.1.0?

Does the tree outside stand a chance if I start attacking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake when writing the `publisher` function:

```
foreverR $ do
    bs <- await
    finallyF (ZMQ.close s M.>> ZMQ.term c M.>> print "ZMQ socket closed") $ do
         (liftU $ ZMQ.send s [] bs)
         (liftU (print "Sending message"))
```

You probably wanted to place the `finallyF` OUTSIDE the `foreverR` loop:

```
finallyF (...) $ foreverR $ do
    bs <- await
    liftU $ ZMQ.send s [] bs)
    liftU (print "Sending message")
```

The way you wrote it, it finalizes after each send, so it's doing exactly what you told it to do: finalize after every send.  `finallyF` calls the finalizer once the action it wraps is complete, both if it terminates successfully or unsuccessfully.  You could also use `catchF` in that case, since the loop never terminates anyway:

```
 catchF (...) $ foreverR $ do
    bs <- await
    liftU $ ZMQ.send s [] bs)
    liftU (print "Sending message")
```

Alternatively, you could have kept it inside the loop but switched to `catchF` so that the finalizer doesn't get run after each send:

```
foreverR $ do
    bs <- await
    catchF (ZMQ.close s M.>> ZMQ.term c M.>> print "ZMQ socket closed") $ do
         (liftU $ ZMQ.send s [] bs)
         (liftU (print "Sending message"))
```

Also, if you are planning on writing a zeroMQ library based on pipes, keep in touch with me because I'm planning to return frames back to an ordinary monad in the next release with a lot of new enhancements to functionality, too, such as the ability to close and reinitialize resources.  To reach me use my gmail.com address with username Gabriel439.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel both for the answer to this question and the nice pipes package.

Comment: @Eric I forgot to mention that you probably want the first or second example as the latter one will not catch anything.  `catchF` and `finallyF` only intercept pipe termination, but there is no chance of another pipe terminating when you only run actions in just the base monad.